# Why am I getting null exception here?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Well, it seems pretty strange. I'm kind of initialiing the variable and it works in the constructor right after the initialization, however in the draw method it doesn't work anymore...

Well here's the code and I'm getting the exception whenever I try to call any method of the object position in the method draw():

```
public class GlText extends GraphicObject {

String fullText = "";

public GlText(Bounds bounds) {
    this.bounds = bounds;
    this.position = getPosition();
    System.out.println("BLOGAS: " + position.getX());
}

@Override
public void draw(Graphics g, AlignStrategy align) {
    g.setColor(Color.orange);
    g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 36));

    FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics();
    int textHeight = metrics.getHeight();
    int textWidth = metrics.stringWidth(fullText);

    // drawing position is recalculated according to text size, etc...
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    // calculating x according to text width



    // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! the Null pointer exception happens in the next line:
    System.out.println("POSITION " + position.getX());**
    System.out.println("TEXTWIDTH " + textWidth);
    System.out.println("BOUNDS " + bounds.getX());
    if (position.getX() - textWidth < bounds.getX())
        x = bounds.getX();
    else
        x = position.getX() - textWidth;

    // calculating y according to text height
    if (position.getY() - textHeight < bounds.getY())
        y = bounds.getY();
    else
        y = position.getY() - textHeight;


    Bounds drawPos = new Bounds(x, y, textWidth, textHeight);       

    // ADDED ALIGN STRATEGY
    Bounds alignedPosition = (Bounds) align.getAligned(drawPos, bounds);

    g.drawString(fullText, alignedPosition.getX(), alignedPosition.getY());


}

public final Bounds getPosition() {

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        Random random = new Random();
        random.setSeed(System.nanoTime());

        x = bounds.getX() + random.nextInt(bounds.getWidth());
        y = bounds.getY() + random.nextInt(bounds.getHeight());

        Bounds newPosition = new Bounds(x, y, 0, 0);
        return newPosition;


}
```

Here's how the exception looks like:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at GraphicObjectPkg.GlText.draw(GlText.java:43)
```

And here's my abstract class which I'm extending with GlText:

```
public abstract class GraphicObject {
    protected Bounds bounds = new Bounds();
    protected Bounds position = null;

    public abstract void draw(Graphics g, AlignStrategy align);
}
```

OK, this is the place where the constructor is called, hmm, it's called from outside and yet the constructo does print the line "BLOGAS: 180":

```
GlText myText = new GlText(currentBounds);
        myText.setFullText("gerai");
        mainGroup.addChild(myText);
```

Final Edit:
Thanks everybody for helping me, due to your help, I finally identified the problem and it was this leftover:

```
public void setFullText(String fullText) {
    this.fullText = fullText;
    position = null;
}
```

I had modified the class and I totally forgot this method had such thing... I found this by using the find command, so I guess the moral of the story for me this time is that whether it seems like you haven't created any other variables, it's better to test it with the find function on the editor...

Comment: Is it possible that you have a name collision with another `position` variable?

Comment: @Keppil Well I tried adding this - System.out.println("POSITION " + this.position.getX()); But it gets the null pointer exception in the same place :S

Comment: When is the constructor for GlText executed? If you don't execute the constructor, the `position`-object will be NULL.

Comment: Are you sure that you are calling the constructor GlText(Bounds)? It may be that you are initializing it with default constructor that is implicit in the parent class

Comment: Could you also post stack trace?

Comment: @Tim I wish I had an idea how to do that... People are always asking, I don't know how to do that... :/

Comment: @Arturas Just look where your error stream gets posted. Which kind of app is that? Web or desktop?

Comment: How you understood that exactly the line was throwing exception without a stack trace? If you were not sure, the most probably bounds object in the constructor is null.

Comment: @ArturasM: What I meant by name collision was that you could have declared a `position` variable in your `GlText` class too, hiding the one inherited from `GraphicObject`. That would cause this behaviour, and wouldn't be affected by adding `this.` before the variable.

Comment: @Tim Well, I debugged it and it threw it at that place where it was calling the this.position.getX();  I use NetBeans IDE and that's a normal swing application.

Comment: @Keppil Thanks. It wasn't exactly what you mean in your last comment but it was you that helped me identify the problem here. I didn't have another variable called like that, but it seems something was left out after I was rebuilding the app for the decorator to work and by using the find command I found: 
public void setFullText(String fullText) {
        this.fullText = fullText;
        position = null;
    }
So when I set the text, I used to reset the position, though I needn't do it now and indeed it was destructive...

Answer (score 1):

If draw is a callback event and if the framework doesn't use your constructed object then you will get `NullPointerException`.

You need to ensure framework uses passed object while calling draw method you can simply do it using `==` operator in `draw` method.

Store the reference in the constructor to a object of `GlText`

```
private final GlText customized = null;
//Inside Constructor 
 customized = this;
```

Inside `draw` method

```
 if(this != customized )
 {
    System.out.println("Objects are different");
 }
```

Hardway is to understand framework and check how `draw` method is getting called:-)